# How can I make apt-mirror to save repositories files on router-provided FTP server?

Tags: networking, permissions, ftp, apt-mirror

I have an external HDD connected to my WRT1900AC router, which has built-in ftp support. The ftp access is user and password protected.

I'd like to use apt-mirror to download the Ubuntu repositories in the external hard drive.

I tried modifying:

```
/etc/apt/mirror.list
```

setting the base_path as follows:

```
ftp://marcelo:mypassword@192.168.1.1/linux/apt-mirror
```

the folder /linux/apt-mirror exists in the ftp server and I have write permissions on it.

When I execute apt-mirror I get:

```
sudo apt-mirror 
apt-mirror: can't create ftp://marcelo:mypassword@192.168.1.1/linux/apt-mirror/mirror directory at /usr/bin/apt-mirror line 342.
```

The reason I want to do this is to allow anyone in my LAN to access the repositories and not use the limited space in my laptop SSD.

Comment: i don't think apt-mirror supports creating a mirror on an ftp server. maybe you could mount it and use the mount location as the base_path

Comment: if that's the case, and I have apt-mirror in a cron task to run everyday,  how can I manage the situation when my laptop is not connected to my network (traveling)? I don't want it to populate a local folder (it will not have mounted the network share in that case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the following script in case anyone is interested.

The script mounts a samba share in the local file system, executes apt-mirror, and unmount the samba share when it finished.

This is pretty much my first scrip ever, so I am sure there is lots of room for improvement

```
#!/bin/bash
# This scripts expects cifs-utils installed and apt-mirror 
# installed and configured, and all samba shares properly configured


######### Variables Definition ##############

mountDir='/mnt/apt-mirrors'
sambaShare="//myserver/apt-mirrors"
sambaUser="myUser"
sambaPwd="mySambaPassword"

######### End Variables Definition ##########

clear

echo
echo "********** Starting Execution **********"
echo

if [ ! -d $mountDir ]; then
    echo "creating dir: $mountDir.."
    mkdir $mountDir
    echo "$mountDir created"
else
    echo "dir $mountDir exists"
fi

mounted () {
    eval "grep -qs $mountDir /proc/mounts"
}

echo

if mounted; then
    echo "something is mounted in $mountDir. Unmounting..."
    umount -f $mountDir
    echo
fi

echo "mounting share $sambaShare in dir $mountDir..."
mount -t cifs -o username=$sambaUser,password=$sambaPwd $sambaShare $mountDir 

if mounted; then
    echo "samba share $sambaShare successfuly mounted"
    echo
    echo "********* starting apt-mirror **********"
    echo
    (exec /usr/bin/apt-mirror)
    echo
    echo "********* apt-mirror finished **********"
    echo
    echo "unmounting $mountDir"
    umount -l $mountDir
fi

echo

if ! mounted; then
    echo "unmount successful"
else
    echo "something went wrong: $sambaShare is still mounted"
    echo "forcing unmount..."
    umount -f $mountDir
fi

echo

echo "cleaning $mountDir..."
rm -r $mountDir

echo
echo "********** Execution Finished **********"

exit
```

You can replace the values of the variables to fit your needs