# Is there a simple way to configure apt-get to optimize downloads using a lan apt-mirror when available?

Tags: networking, apt, package-management, updates, repository

I have a laptop and a local copy of several repositories in an external hard drive connected to my router. My router provides access to those files (with credentials) as samba shares and/or ftp server.

I would like to configure apt-get to check those repositories when they are available and download updates from them to speed up the process when possible.

To be more clear: I want apt-get to check both the regular repositories in the internet and my local one when my laptop is connected to my wifi. If files in the external repositories are newer than the ones in my local mirror or if the mirror is not available, apt-get should download the files from the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this and it's working pretty well, so I want to share it with people that want to implement something similar.

My first problem was that my system supports multi-arch, so the mirrored repositories should contain both i386 and amd64 packages (I did not mirrored sources) to avoid downloading errors. This is done in **/etc/apt/mirror.list** like this example shows:

```
deb-i386  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

My **base_path** defined in that file is **/mnt/apt-mirrors**, and I run a script that mounts an external hard drive connected to the USB port of my router as a Samba share (you can see the script here: 
[how to use apt-mirror to save files in HDD connected to LAN router](https://askubuntu.com/questions/680569/how-can-i-make-apt-mirror-to-save-repositories-files-on-router-provided-ftp-serv/681982#681982)

I wanted to access the mirrored repositories from other computers in the LAN, so the other part of the solution is adding the FTP repositories definitions **at the beginning** in **/etc/apt/sources.list**. This setup makes **apt-get** to use the FTP repositories first when downloading files and then use the ones defined in **/etc/apt/sources.list.d**, provided the mirrored ones are up to date.

The local repositories are defined like this:

```
deb [arch=amd64,i386] ftp://user:password@lan-resource/apt-mirrors/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse
```

where you replace **user** with the user name that has access granted to the FTP server, **:password** with its password if required to connect (otherwise remove), and **lan-resource** with the address of the FTP server in your LAN (I decided to edit **/etc/hosts** to avoid repeating hard-coded IP address, where I defined 192.168.0.1 as **lanftpserver** to use in this field).

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 steps to setting up your own repository

1. Install `dpkg-dev`
2. Put the packages in a directory
3. Create a script that will scan the packages and create a file `apt-get update` can read
4. Add a line to your `sources.list` pointing at your repository

#### Install `dpkg-dev`

Open a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
```

#### The Directory

Create a directory to keep your packages. For this example, we'll be using `/usr/local/lan-repo`.

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lan-repo
```

Now move all your packages into that new directory.

Packages that have been downloaded already are usually stored on your system in `/var/cache/apt/archives`. If you have installed `apt-cacher` you will most likely have additional packages stored in the `apt-cacher/packages` directory.

#### Create a script named `update-lan-repo`

It's a very simple three line script:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /usr/local/lan-repo
sudo dpkg-scanpackages . /dev/null | gzip -9c > packages.gz
```

Copy and paste the above into your favorite text editor, and save it as `update-lan-repo` in `~/bin`. (`~` means the home directory. If `~/bin` doesn't exist already then create it. Ubuntu will automatically put that directory in your PATH. This makes it a good place to put personal scripts.)

**Now let's make the script executable:**

```
chmod u+x ~/bin/update-lan-repo
```

**Here's how the script works:**

`dpkg-scanpackages` looks at all the packages in `lan-repo`, and the output is compressed and written to the file `packages.gz`, which `apt-get update` can read (see below for a reference that explains this in full detail). `/dev/null` is an empty file - that is - it's a makeshift for an override file which holds some additional information about the packages, which in our case is not really needed. See [`deb-override(5)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/deb-override.5) if you want to find out more about it.

**We need to add your local repo to your sources.list file**

```
echo "deb file:/usr/local/lan-repo ./" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and that's it you're done.

#### CD/DVD Option

You can store the directory containing the .deb file to a CD/DVD and use that as a repository as well (good for sharing between computers). To use the CD as a repository:

**simply run the command:**

```
sudo apt-cdrom add
```

using the new repository.

**Then whenever you store a new debian package in the lan-repo directory, run:**

```
sudo update-lan-repo
sudo apt-get update
```

Now your local packages can be manipulated with Synaptic, aptitude and the apt commands: `apt-get`, `apt-cache`, etc. When you attempt to apt-get install, any dependencies will be resolved for you, as long as they can be met.

Comment: I have a two questions about your solution. I assume you want me to use my mounted samba share location (replacing /usr/local/lan-repo).
Does dpkg-scanpackages reads all the content via the lan and then saves the compressed output over the lan? Isn't there a way to avoid this back and forth?

Comment: Also I tried the commands at the promt line and everything goes well until I run dpkg-scanpackages as sudo:

"Packages.gz: Permission Denied"
dpkg-scanpackages: warning: package libqt4-sql-psql (filename ./mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qt4-x11/libqt4-sql-psql_4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb) is repeat;

dpkg-scanpackages: warning: ignored that one and using data from ./mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qt4-x11/libqt4-sql-psql_4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb!

The last 2 lines repeat for every package I cached using apt-mirror

Comment: I'm quite busy at the moment but as to not keep you waiting.. I forgot to add 'sudo' to `dpkg-scanpackages` I have now edited to fix this. that should solve that issue, I havent done this in a long time but i will look into the issue of using the mirror instead of the local cache. And i will be back here this evening.